# how is seam proxying classes

Tags: seam, proxy-classes

seam actually proxies every class for interception. is there a difference between proxied classes and proxied classes that implement interfaces?? f.e. like in spring where a proxy instance is made implementing all interfaces specified in the class.

has someone any performance experiences between java.lang.reflect.Proxy vs. cglib or javassist? isn't instantiation over Proxy much faster than bytecode manipulation??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there many comparison on the web like [this](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=45089):

```
Unproxied: 559009(ns) 5(ms)
cglib: 21374225(ns) 213(ms)
Proxy: 16506009(ns) 165(ms)
```

you can download the code and run it yourself.